# Can I use a std::smatch object with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, regex, smart-pointers, stdmap

I have a following code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

const constexpr static auto kDirectoryToBeSearched = "~/projects";

std::vector<std::string> testPaths = {
   "invalid/path1",
   "test/dir1",
   "test/dir2",
   "invalid/path0",
};

bool findPaths(std::filesystem::path directoryToBeSearched, std::string pattern, std::map<std::filesystem::path, std::shared_ptr<std::smatch>>& pathsFound)
{
   bool status = false;
   
   std::filesystem::path fspath;
   std::regex expression(pattern);

   for(const auto &path : testPaths)
   {
      std::shared_ptr<std::smatch> match = std::make_shared<std::smatch>();
      fspath = directoryToBeSearched / path;
      std::string str = fspath.string();

      std::cout << "\nSearching in the path: " << str << "\n";

      
      if (std::regex_search(str, *match, expression))
      {
         std::cout << "Found pattern!\n";
         status = true;
         pathsFound[fspath] = match;
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "Not found\n";
      }
      
   }

   return status;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<std::filesystem::path, std::shared_ptr<std::smatch>> paths;

   if(findPaths(std::filesystem::path(kDirectoryToBeSearched), R"(test/dir([0-9]+))", paths))
   {
      std::cout << "\nFound some paths!\n";

      for(const auto &path : paths)
      {
         std::cout << "Path: " << path.first << "\n";
         std::cout << "Value found in the path: " << path.second->str(1) << "\n\n";
      }
   }
}
```

The goal is to found all correct patterns in the paths defined in the `testPaths` vector. To do that I have a simple factory function which fills my `std::map` object with matched paths and a regex result.

However, the output of above code is different than what I would expect:

```
Searching in the path: ~/projects/invalid/path1
Not found

Searching in the path: ~/projects/test/dir1
Found pattern!

Searching in the path: ~/projects/test/dir2
Found pattern!

Searching in the path: ~/projects/invalid/path0
Not found

Found some paths!
Path: "~/projects/test/dir1"
Value found in the path: 2

Path: "~/projects/test/dir2"
Value found in the path: 2
```

My understanding is it should return values 1 and 2, since I have two directories named dir1 and dir2, respectively. Instead of that the output points to values 2 and 2. What's wrong with that code? I think it overwrites the first pointer to the `std::smatch` object but don't understand why.

Comment: From what I recall an `std::smatch` is essentially just a pair of iterators that reference the searched `std::string`.  When that searched `std::string` goes out of scope any associated `std::smatch` that refers to it will be invalidated.  Based on that this looks like undefined behaviour.

Comment: [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results): Because `std::match_results` holds `std::sub_matches`, each of which is a pair of iterators into the original character sequence that was matched, it's undefined behavior to examine `std::match_results` if the original character sequence was destroyed or iterators to it were invalidated for other reasons.